# Removing elements while iterating. removeIf result in ConcurrentModificationException

Tags: java, collections

I'm trying to remove elements from a set (someObjectSet) while looping through it.
As I googled, using removeIf should avoid ConcurrentModificationException in this case.
However this doesn't work for me.

Did google lie to me (or I misundertood it), or I'm not using removeIf correctly?

```java
Set<SomeObject> someObjectSet = new HashSet<>();
someObjectSet.add(obj1);
someObjectSet.add(obj2);
someObjectSet.add(obj3);

for (SomeObject obj : someObjectSet ){
    ...
    someObjectSet.removeIf(ele -> if ele satisfies some condition)
}
```

The reason I want to do removeif inside the loop is that, in each loop, it can be determined that some other elements of the set no longer need to go in the loop, therefore I’m removing it so that the for loop won’t pick them up again.

For example,
In loop1, `obj1` gets picked.
Then in the same loop it finds out `obj2` no longer needs to be processed => remove `obj2` from the set.
In loop2, instead of `obj2`, `obj3` is picked up

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't iterate and `removeIf` using elements of your iteration. Beside the problem you're experiencing right now, those calls amount to iterating through the entire collection for each element of the collection (so you're still removing from the collection while iterating, which explains the exception!).

`removeIf` iterates for you, so all you need is a predicate of `SomeObject`:

```
//no loop
someObjectSet.removeIf(ele -> if ele satisfies some condition);
```

Where `ele -> if ele satisfies some condition` is the condition that *each `SomeObject` element will be tested against* (the ones passing the test will be removed). `forEach` will orchestrate the test on all elements in `someObjectSet`, you don't need to do that.

---

If you're having a secondary condition based on which you want to remove elements, then you can compose predicates (with `or`), something like in this example:

```
Set<Integer> set = new HashSet<>(Set.of(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9));

Predicate<Integer> predicate = s -> s % 2 == 0;
Predicate<Integer> predicate2 = predicate.or(s -> s % 3 == 0);
set.removeIf(predicate2);

// Test with set.removeIf(predicate);
// then with set.removeIf(predicate2);
// and compare results
```

Comment: Thanks @ernest_k. 
The reason I want to do removeif inside the loop is that, in each loop, it can be determined that some other elements of the set no longer need to go in the loop, therefore I’m removing it so that the for loop won’t pick them up again. Do I have to use iterator for this purpose?

Comment: I see. Is it that the lambda expression you pass to `removeIf` cannot cover both of those conditions? That may make an interesting question, so please add a simple example...

Comment: I see what you mean Ernest. I think a more straightforward and simpler solution would be to maintain another toSkipSet and then in each loop, skip if obj is in the toSkipSet.  Even iterator won’t help me in this case?

Comment: @wayne That is normally a good alternative to modifying a collection while iterating through it, and it should work. This answer assumed you want to use `removeIf`. Iterator would be able to achieve it, but your `toSkipSet`-based solution would clearly be better and simpler, in my opinion.

Comment: @wayne so to save some work in the outer iteration, you used `removeIf` *on all elements*, including those you’ve already processed… The solution is not to maintain a growing set of elements to skip, but a queue of element to process: `Queue<SomeObject> queue = new ArrayDeque<>(someObjectSet); while(!queue.isEmpty()) { SomeObject obj = queue.remove(); /* ... */ queue.removeIf(ele -> /*if ele satisfies some condition*/); }`

Comment: Thanks @Holger, queue is indeed a better fit for my purpose